# error while autoposting on twitter {"errors":[{"code":44,"message":"media_ids parameter is invalid."}]}

Tags: php

I am trying to autopost twiter and got following error:

```
{"errors":[{"code":44,"message":"media_ids parameter is invalid."}]}
```

code

```
$media1 = $tweet->upload('media/upload', array('media' => 'E:/wallpaper/xyz.jpg'));

$res=$tweet->post('statuses/update', array(
'status' => $tweetMessage,
    'media_ids' =>  $media1->media_id_string
));
```

Comment: Can your PHP code fetch from the E:/ drive?

Comment: yes.it is fetching  @hd

Answer (score 0):

> I've also started receiving this error. Very strange because one day
>   it worked, and the next day it didn't. Did you ever figure out the
>   cause?
>
> **EDIT:** I figured out where I was having the problem. I was using the
>   `Tweepy library` and had to update the `API.update_status()` call from
>   `update_status(my_tweet)` to `update_status(status=my_tweet)` due to a
>   change in Twitter's API

https://twittercommunity.com/t/media-ids-parameter-is-invalid/12926